# Using fallback fonts

Tags: customization, fonts

I'd like to specify a `FontFamily` that does a fallback if the specified font is not on my system. E.g. I'd like the base font to be `"CMU Serif"`, but if `"CMU Serif"` isn't on the system it'd be nice to have it fallback to say `"Times"` or *some other font of my choosing*.

I tried the obvious idea of specifying a `List`, but that didn't do anything.

Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: does `Options[$FrontEnd, FontSubstitutions]` give anything useful?

Comment: [FontSubstitutions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontSubstitutions.html) and [tutorial/TextAndFontOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextAndFontOptions.html)